# How to open a scene only one time after installing the app in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, load, scene

I just need to make a scene that opens only 1 time when I installed the application when I close and Reopen the application I need it to open from scene 2 not from scene 1 again, is that can be made??

Answer (score 0):

You can save scene opening data with `PlayerPrefs`.

```cs
private const string IsSceneOpened = "IsSceneOpened";

public void Start()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt(IsSceneOpened) == 0)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(IsSceneOpened, 1);

        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1");
    }
    else
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
    }
}
```